# Metamask not returning "code 4001 User rejected the request." when closing login popup in Chrome, but works in Edge

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ethereum, blockchain, metamask

I am trying to connect to the Metamask extension on Chrome by having a button that initiates the log in process on click. However in the event the user closes the log in pop up after clicking the button, no code 4001 exception is thrown in Chrome, the console log is completely empty. After that when I click the button again, it will no longer bring up the log in pop up but instead throw **"RPC Error: Already processing eth_requestAccounts. Please wait."**
[image]

But when I tried in Edge, it throws just fine in the console (this is the expected result):
[image]

Refreshing the Chrome page does not help, I have to close and reopen the entire browser to reset it.

Looking into the extension icon, I noticed that in Edge, whenever I close the login button, the blue "1" notification which signifies pending transactions will be gone:

[image]

However in Chrome that is not the case, the blue "1" notification remains:

[image]

Here is the relevant code for the button if it helps. Any assistance is greatly appreciated:

```
import { Card, CardContent, Button, Grid } from '@material-ui/core'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import MetaMaskOnboarding from '@metamask/onboarding';

function MetaMaskConnectButton(props) {    
    const forwarderOrigin = 'http://localhost:3000';    
    const onboarding = new MetaMaskOnboarding({ forwarderOrigin });    
    const { ethereum } = window;    
    const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState('Connect MetaMask')    
    const [isButtonDisabled, setIsButtonDisabled] = useState(false)    
    const [mmAccounts, setMmAccounts] = useState('')    

    useEffect(() => {        
        if (!isMetaMaskInstalled()) {            
            setButtonText('Click here to install MetaMask!')        
        }
    }, [])    

    useEffect(() => {        
        if (mmAccounts == null || mmAccounts.length === 0)
            setIsButtonDisabled(false)       
        else            
            setIsButtonDisabled(true)    
    }, [mmAccounts])    

    async function metaMaskClientCheck() {        
        if (!isMetaMaskInstalled()) {            
            await metamaskInstall()            
            setIsButtonDisabled(true)        
        } 
        else {            
            await metamaskConnect()            
            setIsButtonDisabled(false)        
        }    
    }    

    //Function checks if the MetaMask extension is installed    
    const isMetaMaskInstalled = () => {        
        //Have to check the ethereum binding on the window object to see if it's installed
          return Boolean(ethereum && ethereum.isMetaMask);    
    }    

    const metamaskInstall = async () => {        
        setButtonText('Onboarding in progress...')        
        setIsButtonDisabled(true)        
        onboarding.startOnboarding();    
    }    

    const metamaskConnect = async () => {        
        setIsButtonDisabled(true)        
        setButtonText('Connecting to MetaMask...')        
        try {            
            // Will open the MetaMask UI            
            let accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' }) 
            console.log('Ethereum Request over')            
            let account = accounts[0]            
            setMmAccounts(account)            
            setButtonText('MetaMask Connected')        
        } catch (error) {            
            console.error(error);            
            setIsButtonDisabled(false)            
            setButtonText('Connect MetaMask')        
        }    
    };    

    return (        
        <Grid container xs={12} sm={12}>
            <Grid container xs={6} sm={6} justify='flex-start'>
                <Button                    
                    disabled={isButtonDisabled}                    
                    variant='contained'                    
                    color='secondary'
                    className='button-blue originalText'
                    onClick={() => {
                        metaMaskClientCheck()
                    }}
                    classes={{ root: 'ng-button-filled-secondary' }}
                >
                    {buttonText}
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    )}
export default MetaMaskConnectButton
```

Comment: I have also tried to clear cache/cookies/browser history, update Google Chrome to latest, and restart my machine.

Comment: Still facing this issue at the moment, does anyone have any idea? I have even opened a bug ticket here https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/18012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a timeout to your current code and thrown an error like this:

```js
   let timeout;
async function metamaskConnect() {
  setIsButtonDisabled(true);
  setButtonText('Connecting to MetaMask...');
  try {
    let accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
    console.log('Ethereum Request over');
    let account = accounts[0];
    setMmAccounts(account);
    setButtonText('MetaMask Connected');
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setIsButtonDisabled(false);
      setButtonText('Connect MetaMask');
    }, 5000);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    setIsButtonDisabled(false);
    setButtonText('Connect MetaMask');
  }
}
```

Or maybe use Promise.reject or thrown new Error as another option.

Comment: Oh wow, i didn't think about using a timeout of Promise.reject. Thanks Theo...

Comment: My pleasure. Whenever possible please accept as an acceptable answer. I am thriving my way to the top, LOL!

Answer (score 1):

Chrome metamask behaves funky. I just had an issue with metamask chrome [asked here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/145603/jsonrpcengine-response-has-no-error-or-result-for-request). It was working on mozilla and brave but not on chrome. I disabled all the extensions (you should try this) but error still occurred. My main machine is Linux and when I started the same app on macos chrome, it worked.

You can [read a long discussion here](https://forum.moralis.io/t/metamask-rpc-error-jsonrpcengine-response-has-no-error-or-result-for-request/16058). I think the issue is specific to your chrome and device

Comment: That's a little bit of a bummer, seems that the Chrome version is a little unstable. Thanks for the reply and the link. If no one else replies, I will award the bounty to you.

Comment: @Cheryl Try your code in a different machine with chrome. It should work